# What is difference between `loadChildren: () => import('./hoge.module.ts).then(m => m.HogeModule)' and loadChildren: './hoge.module#HogeModule'?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-module, angular-load-children

**Issue**

We get an error `cannot find module` in case following structure.

> app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: CHILD_MANAGEMENT_PORTAL.baseUrl,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: EnvelopeComponent,
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/child-management/child-management.module').then(
        m => m.ChildManagementModule
      ),
    data: {
      menuResolver: ChildManagementMenuResolver,
      pageTitleResolver: ChildManagementPageTitleResolver,
      portalData: CHILD_MANAGEMENT_PORTAL
    }
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

> child-management-routing.module.ts : wrong

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: './dashboard/child-dashboard.module#ChildDashboardModule'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class SalesArrangementManagementRoutingModule {}
```

We could solve this error by only changing loadChildren of child routing.module from `loadChildren: './hoge.module#HogeModule'` to `loadChildren: () => import('./hoge.module.ts).then(m => m.HogeModule)'`.

> child-management-routing.module.ts : correct

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/child-dashboard.module').then(m => m.ChildDashboardModule)
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class SalesArrangementManagementRoutingModule {}
```

But I could not understand why. (I did not change app-routing.module.ts...)

So could you explain the difference?

Comment: If you think my answer is correct or other any answer do mark it as correct answer as it helps others who comes to this question to find right answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you upgraded from Angular 7.x to 8.x and this is where the scheme changed.

**Explanation** (From angular docs)

> When Angular first introduced lazy routes, there wasn't browser support for dynamically loading additional JavaScript. Angular created our own scheme using the syntax loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' and built tooling to support it. Now that ECMAScript dynamic import is supported in many browsers, Angular is moving toward this new syntax.
>
> In version 8, the string syntax for the loadChildren route specification was deprecated, in favor of new syntax that uses import() syntax.
>
> **Before**
>
> ```
> const routes: Routes = [{
>   path: 'lazy',
>   // The following string syntax for loadChildren is deprecated
>   loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'
> }];
> ```
>
> **After**
>
> ```
> const routes: Routes = [{
>   path: 'lazy',
>   // The new import() syntax
>    loadChildren: () => import('./lazy/lazy.module').then(m => m.LazyModule)
> }];
> ```

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

This is feature is updated from previous version so if it need to work in your application slight changes to be made 
here is a example have a look

error ts1323: dynamic import is only supported when '--module' flag is 'commonjs' or 'esnext

I got the first error when i tried using static lazy loading import

```
loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule
```

i decided to use dynamic import

```
loadChildren: () => import('./lazy/lazy.module').then(m => m.LazyModule)
```

This threw the second error.

I then fixed it by simply adding "module": "esNext" to compilerOptions in tsconfig.json file and updated "module": "es2015" to "module": "esNext" in both tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.tns.json files.

That solve the problem for me